# eventlistener for backbutton not working in cordova app with multiple html files

Tags: javascript, android, html, events

I have a html5/jquery/cordova app for Android, and I need to control the Android backbutton.
The app contains 3 html files, each containing 3 div's with data-role='page':

1. index.html (#index01, #index02, #index03)
2. cars.html (#cars01, #cars02, #cars03)
3. cities.html (#cities01, #cities02, #cities03)

A menu navigates between the 3 files, each page has a button to navigate to the next page.

To control the behaviour of the Android backbutton, each of these files contains an eventlistener: `document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);`

My `scripts.js` file contains `function onBackKeyDown() {...}` where the desired behaviour is specified. For now I do not have a problem with the contents of this function.

(FYI: when I press the backbutton from `#index01` I want to exit the app, when I press the backbutton from `#cars01` or `#cities01` I want to navigate to `#index01` and when I'm on one of the other pages I want to navigate to the 'previous' page. But: My question is not about this navigation!)

The problem that I **do** have, is that `onBackKeyDown` is only triggered when I'm on index.html. Whenever I navigate to cars.html or cities.html, from there to one of the subpages, and then press the Android backbutton, my function `onBackKeyDown` is never called.
I've tested this by putting `alert("backbutton pressed");` as the very first line in the function. This alert only shows on index.html, not on the other two files.

So my question to you is: Does anybody know why this doesn't work? Or - even better - can anybody provide a solution? I've been struggling for weeks now.

Comment: Provide more details on the routing schema of your app.

Comment: The method i use is the initialpage loaded is a container for subsequent screens in the application.  On that initial page load the backbutton event should be listened for onDeviceReady.  Then routing is handled by a function to create an ajax query and update the initial pages container with the html.  Scripts in external files won't run this way so the initial file must have the scripts included for other pages in the apllication.  I usually set event listeners on the container page and then watch for elements in the event.target to match certain classes or ids that I need to do things with.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the comments, they helped me in the right direction.
Since I'm not using routing in my app, just 'basic' html pageflow, I realised there is no container around all the pages.

Furthermore the backbutton event is only part of the cordova library. And until now I only needed this on the main page. But since I want to have the backbutton functionality on all of my html documents, **the solution was to add cordova.js to every one of the html documents**.